# SciPy - from_rotvec() taking no keyword arguments

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to undertake a 3D transformation using SciPy using a rotation vector that is in degrees.

I am using the following to test the setup:

```py
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
import numpy as np

vector = np.array([1, 0, 0])
r = R.from_rotvec(np.array([0, 0, 90]), degrees=True)
```

however, it is throwing the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-73e8ed4e3d51> in <module>
      1 vector = np.array([1, 0, 0])
----> 2 r = R.from_rotvec(np.array([0, 0, 90]), degrees=True)
      3 r.as_matrix()

TypeError: from_rotvec() takes no keyword arguments
```

The documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_rotvec.html) states that `from_rotvec` should take `degrees=True` as a keyword argument (and I actually took my test example from the SciPy docs).

Does anyone know why this TypeError is being generated?

Comment: What version of SciPy are you using? Is it the same on that the docs reference?

Comment: Good point. I was on 1.6.2 and the docs 1.7.1. Have updated and working now. Noob error, face palm

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: Would you mind upvoting my question? But yes, I have done

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are running a different version of SciPy than the one the documents are describing.